# NetworkOnMainThread even when using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the below code I got an error when running my Android project for reading Json and it shows NetworkOnMainThread exception, i used Async task and tried to enable strict mode but nothing helps

```
public class Recepti extends Activity {
    TextView tablica,tablica1,cijena,opis;
    Upravljanje up= new Upravljanje();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recepti);

        cijena=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tablica1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tablica=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        opis=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        new Asink().execute();
    }
   protected class Asink extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           tablica.setText(up.getData());
           tablica1.setText(up.getData1());
           opis.setText(up.opis());
           return null;
       }


   }



}
and heres the part of code that logcat led me to
public  Upravljanje(){

    try{
        HttpClient klijent = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post =new HttpPost("http://localhost/series/nabavisastojke.php");
        HttpResponse response =  klijent.execute(post);
        if(response!=null) {
            HttpEntity entitet = response.getEntity();
           isr=entitet.getContent();
        }else{
            Log.e("log..tag","no response" );
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log..tag","error in connecting"+e.toString() );
    }
```

NOTE: i only wrote localhost here, in my app i wrote ip adress

Comment: Use your localhost ip address if you in any network

Comment: just put this line in doInBackground() : Upravljanje up= new Upravljanje();

Comment: Moreover, you are manipulating UI in background thread. Read https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

You are doing network I/O in the constructor for `Upravljanje`, and you are executing that constructor on the main application thread. Have that network I/O be performed on the thread supplied by `doInBackground()`.

Also, as beigleux notes, you are attempting to modify the UI (`TextView` widgets) in `doInBackground()`. That will not work. Move that code into an `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask` subclass.

You may wish to review [the documentation for `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
public class Recepti extends Activity {
TextView tablica,tablica1,cijena,opis;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recepti);

    cijena=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tablica1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tablica=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    opis=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    new Asink().execute();
}
protected class Asink extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
     Upravljanje up= new Upravljanje();

       return null;
       }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    tablica.setText(up.getData());
    tablica1.setText(up.getData1());
    opis.setText(up.opis());
  }
}
```

you've made two mistakes:

1- You've initialized your `Upravljanje` class in main thread.

2- you've used `setText()` method in `doInBackground()`which is not work. you must move those codes to `onPostExecute()` method.